# test springboot restcontroller consume json and optional file using postman

Tags: json, spring-boot, postman

i have a rest endpoint in my controller like this..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createFoo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createFoo(@RequestPart(name = "foo") Foo foo,
                                      @RequestPart(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    service.createFoo(foo, file);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

how can i test this out using postman and curl? i need to send a json foo with or without a file. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can shorten it like this `@PostMapping("/createFoo")`

Firstly specify your method Post and url that postman requested it than
select form-data under Body section

Click key input area and change text to File

In addition parameter name need to be same as form-data variable

Example attached
[image: postman request with file]